# Is there an equivalent to RSpec's before(:all) in MiniTest?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

Since it now seems to have replaced TestUnit in 1.9.1, I can't seem to find an equivalent to this. There **are** times when you really just want a method to run once for the suite of tests.
For now I've resorted to some lovely hackery along the lines of:

```
Class ParseStandardWindTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  @@reader ||= PolicyDataReader.new(Time.now)  
  @@data ||= @@reader.parse  
  def test_stuff  
    transaction = @@data[:transaction]  
    assert true, transaction  
  end  
end
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756488/ruby-minitest-suite-or-class-level-setup and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881474/before-after-suite-when-using-ruby-minitest

Answer (score 3):

Nops, there's only **setup** and **teardown** and both are run before/after every test. But your solution seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use 'let' I've found.

eg (using `minitest/spec`)

```
describe "my amazing test" do

  let(:reader) { PolicyDataReader.new(Time.now) }
  let(:data) {reader.parse}

  it "should parse" do
    transaction = data[:transaction]
    transaction.must_equal true
  end

end
```

to use `minitest/spec` simply add

```
gem 'minitest', require: ['minitest/autorun', 'minitest/spec']
```

to the test group of your `Gemfile`