# Before/After Suite when using Ruby MiniTest

Tags: ruby, test-suite, minitest

Is there an alternative to RSpec's `before(:suite)` and `after(:suite)` in MiniTest?

I suspect that a custom test runner is in order, however I cannot imagine it is not a common requirement, so somebody has probably implemented in. :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are `setup()` and `teardown()` methods available. The documentation also lists `before()` and `after()` as being available.

Edit: Are you looking to run something before each test or before or after the whole suite is finished?

Comment: `setup/teardown` and `before/after` run after *each* test. I need to run something before and after *all* tests.

Comment: [Try this](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Unit.html#method-c-after_tests)  Nickolay -- after_tests()

Comment: Thanks, Caley! I don't know how I missed it. :-)

Comment: nothing for before_tests though, dammit.  I can't believe this still doesn't exist outside of rspec after all these years.

Comment: Update to my comment on May 4, 2011 -- The new documentation appears to be [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit.html). The first method listed shows after_tests()

Comment: Github issue for a before(all) method to run once per TestCase: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/61 and article related to this topic: http://chriskottom.com/blog/2014/10/4-fantastic-ways-to-set-up-state-in-minitest/

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18422499/1314725) for running code after the whole suite is finished with Minitest > 5.0

Comment: @CaleyWoods `after_tests` is now replaced by `after_run`

Comment: Refer to Gert's answer for before all functionality.

Answer (score 25):

As noted above in Caley's answer and comments, `MiniTest::Unit` contains the function `after_tests`. There is no `before_tests` or equivalent, but any code in your `minitest_helper.rb` file should be run before the test suite, so that will do the office of such a function.

Caveat: Still relatively new at Ruby, and very new at Minitest, so if I'm wrong, *please* correct me! :-)

Comment: I believe this assumes that you `load` your test_helper/mintest_helper. If you use `require` then it will only load once and thus only run once

Comment: Well... Yeah. Exactly. It'll run once, before the tests begin.

Answer (score 21):

To get this to work with the current version of Minitest (5.0.6) you need to `require 'minitest'` and use `Minitest.after_run { ... }`.

```
warn "MiniTest::Unit.after_tests is now Minitest.after_run. ..."
```

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest.rb
https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/unit.rb

Answer (score 6):

To run code before *each* test, use `before`. You're operating here in the context of an instance, possibly of a class generated implicitly by `describe`, so instance variables set in `before` are accessible in each test (e.g. inside an `it` block).

To run code before *all* tests, simply wrap the tests in a class, a subclass of `MiniTest::Spec` or whatever; now, before the tests themselves, you can create a class or module, set class variables, call a class method, etc., and all of that will be available in all tests.

Example:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class MySpec < MiniTest::Spec
  class MyClass
  end
  def self.prepare
    puts "once"
    @@prepared = "prepared"
    @@count = 0
  end
  prepare
  before do
    puts "before each test"
    @local_count = (@@count += 1)
  end
  describe "whatever" do
    it "first" do
      p MyClass
      p @@prepared
      p @local_count
    end
    it "second" do
      p MyClass
      p @@prepared
      p @local_count
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the output, along with my comments in braces explaining what each line of the output proves:

```
once [this code, a class method, runs once before all tests]

Run options: --seed 29618 [now the tests are about to run]
# Running tests:

before each test [the before block runs before each test]
MySpec::MyClass [the class we created earlier is visible in each test]
"prepared" [the class variable we set earlier is visible in each test]
1 [the instance variable from the before block is visible in each test]

before each test [the before block runs before each test]
MySpec::MyClass [the class we created earlier is visible in each test]
"prepared" [the class variable we set earlier is visible in each test]
2 [the instance variable from the before block is visible each test]
```

(Note that I do not mean this output to imply any guarantee about the order in which tests will run.)

Another approach is to use the existing `before` but wrap code to run only once in a class variable flag. Example:

```
class MySpec < MiniTest::Spec
  @@flag = nil
  before do
    unless @@flag
      # do stuff here that is to be done only once
      @@flag = true
    end
    # do stuff here that is to be done every time
  end
  # ... tests go here
end
```

Comment: A warning to anyone using the `prepare` idiom above, as I did, in Rails to set up some database records. If you have even a blank file in the `test/fixtures` directory, anything you put in the database through `prepare` will get wiped by fixture setup. Because the variables themselves are still present, weirdness will ensue.

Comment: (Of course, really one should use fixtures for this anyway, I was being naughty).

Answer (score 4):

One simple way to do this is to write a guarded class method, and then call that in a `begin`.

A Minitest::Spec example:

```
describe "my stuff" do
  def self.run_setup_code
    if @before_flag.nil?
      puts "Running the setup code"
      @before_flag = true
    end
  end

  before do
    self.class.run_setup_code
  end

  it "will only run the setup code once" do
    assert_equal 1, 1
  end

  it "really only ran it once" do
    assert_equal 1,1
  end
end
```

...to get

```
Run options: --seed 11380

# Running:

Running the setup code
..

Finished in 0.001334s, 1499.2504 runs/s, 1499.2504 assertions/s.

2 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Nice approach. Curious: why not just hook Ruby's initialize method instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can just place the code outside of the class.

This is what I do to have a banner.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'minitest/test'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class InstanceTest < Minitest::Test

    def setup
    url     = ARGV.first
    @url    = self.validate_instance(url)
        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    end
```

Comment: I voted this answer up but BEWARE, placing code outside the class only works for code that doesn't affect the database. All code outside the class is executed outside the transaction and will clutter the test database if there are any activerecord operations.

Answer (score 0):

Nice thing about minitest is its flexibility. I've been using a custom MiniTest Runner with a +before_suite+ callback. Something like in this example - [Ruby Minitest: Suite- or Class- level setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756488/ruby-minitest-suite-or-class-level-setup#answer-6764734)

And then tell minitest to use the custom runner

```
MiniTest::Unit.runner = MiniTestSuite::Unit.new
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an after test callback by updating your test_helper.rb (or spec_helper.rb) like this

```
# test_helper.rb

class MyTest < Minitest::Unit
  after_tests do
    # ... after test code
  end
end
```