# Before/After methods for Ruby Minitest framework

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm using the latest version of Ruby(2.0.0) and Minitest (5.0.8).

I am looking for a way to create 2 methods, a before and an after.  The before method should run before Minitest even starts on the testcases and the after should run once **ALL** of the test have finished.

I already use the setup() and teardown() methods that run before and after each individual test but I'm looking for something that wraps around the whole Minitest suite.

I have seen:

[Ruby Minitest: Suite- or Class- level setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756488/ruby-minitest-suite-or-class-level-setup#answer-6764734)

and

[Before/After Suite when using Ruby MiniTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881474/before-after-suite-when-using-ruby-minitest)

Which are both out of date with the latest version of Minitest.

Is this still possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `before` method is easy, you just configure your test setup to call a method before the Minitest starts.

The `after` method can be achieve by using the method `Minitest.after_run(&block)` provided by the Minitest API. Ex:

```
Minitest.after_run do
  puts 'All tests finished'
  my_method_call()
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't believe I couldn't find that

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at minitest-hooks. minitest-hooks extends minitest with `before(:all)` and `after(:all)`, which do what you want when the structure of your describe block is flat. When you have nested describe blocks, you may want to take [an approach that is similar to Thiago's answer](http://ruslanledesma.com/2016/07/21/before-all-after-all-in-minitest.html).