# I want to call def setup method before all tests in minitest ruby

Tags: ruby, minitest, selenium-ruby

This is my code

```
class TestLogin < MiniTest::Test

  def setup
    @driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @driver.manage.window.maximize
    @driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
  end

  def test_case1 
    puts "testcase1"
  end

  def test_case2
    puts "testcase2"
  end
end
```

I want to run setup method only once for two testcases at the starting.

Comment: `setup` is defined to run before every test, I do not think there is an easy way to change this.

Comment: So any other way to perform same thing.

Comment: This link may help, lots of discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881474/before-after-suite-when-using-ruby-minitest

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you are actually trying to achieve?  i.e. What would you gain by only having the call performed only once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `minitest-hooks` gem with `before_all` something like:

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require 'minitest/hooks/test'

class TestLogin < MiniTest::Test
  include Minitest::Hooks

  def before_all
    puts "setup .."
  end

  def test_case1
    puts "testcase1"
  end

  def test_case2
    puts "testcase2"
  end
end
```

Now when you run the test you should see something like:

```
Run options: --seed 58346

# Running:

setup ..
testcase1
.testcase2
.

Finished in 0.001259s, 1588.7504 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

2 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```