# How can I use CI:Reporter or Minitest-CI with Minitest custom runner?

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, watir-webdriver, bamboo, minitest

I am trying to run a suite of automated tests on a CI Server written in Ruby with MiniTest. I have written a custom minitest runner a la the question below.

[Ruby Minitest: Suite- or Class- level setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756488/ruby-minitest-suite-or-class-level-setup)

The tests are running web based automation (Watir Webdriver), and I need the custom runner to set up the browser and environment once rather than for each individual test.

I am working to have these tests run on a continuous integration server. I would liketo utilize reporting from either https://github.com/bhenderson/minitest-ci or https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter.

When I try and include these gems, I don't get any reports. With ci-reporter, I get errors indicating that my before_suite code from my custom runner is not getting called.

How can I configure one of these CI reporter gems in order to have it run with my custom minitest runner?

Here is my runner:

```
MiniTest::Unit.autorun

class MyMiniTest
class Unit < MiniTest::Unit

def before_suites
  # code to run before the first test
end

def after_suites
  # code to run after the last test
end

def _run_suites(suites, type)
  begin
    before_suites
    super(suites, type)
  ensure
    after_suites
  end
end

def _run_suite(suite, type)
  begin
    suite.before_suite if suite.respond_to?(:before_suite)
    super(suite, type)
  ensure
    suite.after_suite if suite.respond_to?(:after_suite)
  end
end


MiniTest::Unit.runner = MyMiniTest::Unit.new
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: you say "when I try to include..."  where in your code are you trying to do the include?

Comment: I have attempted to require the gem in both the rake file and the mini_testhelper.rb file that gets loaded into all tests.

Comment: I'm no expert with minitest, but what if you do the requires at the top of the runner?  For CI-reporter you may need to ask this in whatever their preferred support venue is, I don't see a tag for it, which makes me suspect they may not watch stackoverflow

Comment: Rake doesn't know how to build the task without requiring ci:reporter in the rake file.