# Minitest 5 - suite-level set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

How do I run a suite-level set up and teardown (before and after ALL the tests have run) with minitest 5? I am trying to replicate the functionality of custom test runner that was written for rails 3, currently upgrading it to rails 4.

This may appear to be a copy of [Ruby Minitest: Suite- or Class- level setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756488/ruby-minitest-suite-or-class-level-setup?rq=1) but the functionality of .runner has been deprecated in minitest 5.0+

For example I would like these to run before and after all the tests.

```
def before_suites
  # code to run before the first test
  p "Before everything"
end

def after_suites
  # code to run after the last test
  p "After everything"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for similar solution. And here is a proposed solution from [minitest README file](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#how-to-run-code-before-a-group-of-tests):

```
describe Blah do
  SETUP = begin
     # ... this runs once when describe Blah starts
  end
  # ...
end
```

I've tried this, but since i was using some of test_helper support methods, it didn't quite work out for me. I wrote this simple work-around:

```
class SearchServiceTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  @@init = 0

  def setup
    if @@init.eql?(0)
      .. setup code goes here ..  

      @@init = 1
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Not most elegant solution, but worked for me.